# Ubuntu cluster management with torque+maui

Tags: cluster

I am running a small ubuntu cluster with 8 PCs. Regular users should not be able to access the individual PCs. They should only be able to submit computation tasks through qsub.

Also, regular users should have access to storage on the cluster. Ideally, a regular user should not see where his/her files are located on individual PCs. He should see the cluster as a single storage location. And he should have access only to his files.

Moreover, a process running for a particular user should have access to that user's files.

How can I accomplish all this?

Right now the cluster runs on Ubuntu with torque + maui. It has several issues that I need to fix. One of them is that users can ssh to individual PCs and run processes there, violating the queue.

I am new to linux and clusters, so try giving an answer as introductory as possible. Also, links to no-nonsense tutorials on these topics will also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly prohibit running certain programs for common users (however they might still be able to run some interpreted language, if you forbid e.g. `make`, `gcc`).

Better approach would be using `cgroups` (introduced to linux kernel in 2.6.29 - your kernel should support them) or some light virtualization (lxc-containers).

See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/cgroups

With `cgroups` you could limit user to 1 CPU (or even less) and 50MB RAM, which would allow user using ssh access but not really running expensive calculation (if user exceeds limit, the process will be killed).